# Denied a Canadian study visa for insufficient funds - will this hurt my US F1 application?

Tags: visa, canada, student-visa, study, usa

I have tried to apply for a Canadian study visa and I was denied twice based on the fact that I have insufficient funds, though they said I'm free to reapply.

Actually I have the amount they need in the bank for the first year of study.  But I'm tired of waiting those long months of Canadian visas just to denied again.

I want to now apply for a US F1 visa. But rumour has it that once I apply for a Canadian visa and it is refused, I will be automatically denied a US F1 visa because these two countries share information. I wanted to find out how accurate this statement is.

Comment: `But I'm tired of waiting those long months of Canadian visas just to denied again` Fix the issues why you are being denied instead of blaming the Canadian visa officer. It is your duty to give evidence to support your case and not the other way round. `rumour has it that once I apply for a Canadian visa and it is refused` It is a rumour so why do you believe it to be true.

Comment: Questions about moving to another country for studies belong at [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score 5):

You may be misunderstanding what the financial requirements are all about. The Canadians do not **only** want to see if you have enough money in your hands to pay for a year of tuition and living experiences.

- They want to know where the money came from, and if it is *really* yours. If it was a loan, they will wonder how you plan to repay it.
- They want to know if you have a stable lifestyle, with regular incomes and expenditures.

The US will ask *the same kind* of question, so a financial situation that gets you denied in Canada will also get you denied in the US. That is not because Canada and the US exchange information (which they do) but because they look for the same things in respectable visitors.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is inaccurate.

While it's true that the US and Canada share immigration information with each other based on a [bilateral treaty](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/transparency/access-information-privacy/privacy-impact-assessment/us-canada-information-sharing-treaty.html), it's highly unlikely that the Americans will automatically refuse you a visa just because you have had a refusal from Canada in the past. In fact, even a previous US refusal usually does not result in an automatic refusal (unless you've been issued with a ban).

What you CAN expect is that the Canadian refusals will factor into the final decision made by American visa officers. Strictly speaking, your US application will be judged on its own merits, but given your history, you'll need to ensure that it's watertight enough to withstand the additional scrutiny it is likely to receive.